# Design pattern for creating new features in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, pandas

I'm writing a class that takes in a pandas dataframe and creates a bunch of new features based on the preexisting columns in the dataframe. I'd like to take account of the fact that at any given time, some columns that I'm using to generate features might not be present for a given dataset. So before making each feature, check whether the column used to create the feature is present and, if not, add the name of the feature to a list. I'd also like to check whether the feature creation was successful and deal with errors.

The best way that I can think of doing this thus far is to use a dict in combination with exec:

```
mydict = {'preexistingColumn' : ('newfeaturename', "statement"),
          'date' : ('date', "df['date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date'])"),
          'amount' : ('new', "df['new'] = df.groupby('group').amount.apply(f)")}

for key, value in mydict.items():
    if key is not in the dataframe:
        missingFeaturesList.append(V[0])
    try:
        exec v[1]
    except Exception:
        deal with exception
```

This seems a little hackey to me though and was wondering if there might be a more pythonic way to take care of this problem.

Comment: you shouldn't use exec, instead make your functions like this: ``lambda x: x['date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(x['date'])``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `exec`; A better idiom is to do this:

```
In [20]: funcs = { 'foo' : lambda df: Series(10,index=df.index), 'bar' : lambda df: df['foo']+1 }

In [24]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2),columns=list('AB'))

In [25]: for k in ['foo','bar']:
   ....:     if k not in df:
   ....:         df[k] = funcs[k](df)
   ....:         

In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
          A         B  foo  bar
0  0.733404  0.640446   10   11
1  0.927252  0.421439   10   11
2  2.355565  0.839521   10   11
3  0.260136 -0.016420   10   11
4  0.256628 -0.766033   10   11

[5 rows x 4 columns]
```

You can also to some extent use `df.eval` for this in 0.13, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/enhancingperf.html#expression-evaluation-via-eval-experimental)